# Get current Culturecode for query

Tags: 2sxc

I'm trying to get the current culturecode from the token [Dnn.Portal.CultureCode] for the use in a query against the dnnsqldatasource in the where clause but it's not working. I can use @Dnn.Portal.CultureCode in my razor template. Any advise how i can get it in the datasource query?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the DNN docs, there is no token for this - see http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/tokens

If it's possible, I would recommend two possibilities

1. either try to include the code it in the url, and pick it up from there
2. or create an entity which has only the culture field - and write the culture code into the title or something, basically translating the title to "de-de", "en-us", etc. Then use this as a filter criteria, because 2sxc should give you the correct language based on the user context, so it will most likely then give you the correct text, which you would use. Check out the "In" token in queries.